# How to get list<string> * from dynamic library via ctypes to python

Tags: python, ctypes

I have dll and some description to it. I call the methods from this dll and either pass or retrieve information.
So far everything was fine, but I have faced one method, which gives list* and I don't know how to retrieve this format.
Here is the description to it:
Method GetTemplateList requires two parameters for writing: templateList (Type: list *) and templateCount (Type: int *).

C++ usage example:

```
    typedef int (__stdcall *GetTemplateList)(list<tstring> *, int *); 

    GetTemplateList _GetTemplateList; 
    _GetTemplateList = (GetTemplateList) GetProcAddress(my_dll, "GetTemplateList"); 

    list<string> templates;
    int templCnt; 
    _GetTemplateList(&templates, &templCnt);
```

My Python code:

```
class List(Structure):
    _fields_ = ("values", ctypes.c_char * 100)

class DllApi:
... 
    m_pHandle - load library #  works 100%
    m_iLastResultCode - getting result code from dll #  works 100%
... 
    def GetTemplateList(self):
        iTemplateCount = ctypes.c_int()
        templateList = List()
        pGetTemplateList = self.m_pHandle.GetTemplateList #  works 100%
        self.m_iLastResultCode = pGetTemplateList(templateList, ctypes.byref(iTemplateCount))
```

By doing this I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (96 bytes in excess)
```

If I do the same, only change this string:

```
_fields_ = ("values", ctypes.c_char)
```

I get:

```
AIP error: there are null pointers in function parameters;
```

If I don't use List class and use buffer instead:

```
templateList = ctypes.c_buffer(100)
```

I get:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000 (it takes value instead of address)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is `ctypes` not `cpptypes`.  You can't declare the `list<string>` type in `ctypes`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you also explain me, is it ctype library, who doesn't have such type (list<string>)? Because C language works with lists, right?

Comment: C does not support `list<string>`. That is a C++ type.